# Performance of fulltext search in joined tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join, full-text-search

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_organisation` (
  `OrganisationId` bigint(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ShortName` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrganisationId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext` (`Name`,`ShortName`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `dp_organisation_member` (
  `OrganisationId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrganisationId`,`UserId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserId` (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `dp_user` (
  `UserId` bigint(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Alias` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Firstname` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Surname` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `Email` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext` (`Alias`,`Firstname`,`Surname`,`Email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

`dp_organisation` contains all organisations, while `dp_users` contains all users. `dp_organisation_member` is the relationship between users and organisations. Each user is a member of at most one organisation.

Now I would like to search for users matching some string. I want to check both the user's information and the user's organisation's information when doing the search, so the fulltext indexes on both `dp_users` and `dp_organisation` should be used. I created the following query to achieve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_user u
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation_member m ON m.`UserId` = u.`UserId`
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation o ON o.`OrganisationId` = m.`OrganisationId`
WHERE MATCH(u.`Alias`, u.`Firstname`, u.`Surname`, u.`Email`) AGAINST ('foo')
OR MATCH(o.`Name`, o.`ShortName`) AGAINST ('foo')
```

But the query performs really bad. Just to test, I tried the following, which only searches in the user's information:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_user u
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation_member m ON m.`UserId` = u.`UserId`
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation o ON o.`OrganisationId` = m.`OrganisationId`
WHERE MATCH(u.`Alias`, u.`Firstname`, u.`Surname`, u.`Email`) AGAINST ('foo')
```

It runs around 30 times faster.

If I search only in the organisation's information:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_user u
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation_member m ON m.`UserId` = u.`UserId`
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation o ON o.`OrganisationId` = m.`OrganisationId`
WHERE MATCH(o.`Name`, o.`ShortName`) AGAINST ('foo')
```

The query is slow again.

To check that there is nothing wrong with the fulltext index in `dp_organisation`, I reversed the queries to select from `dp_organisation` and join `dp_user`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation o
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation_member m ON m.`OrganisationId` = o.`OrganisationId`
LEFT JOIN dp_user u ON u.`UserId` = m.`UserId`
WHERE MATCH(u.`Alias`, u.`Firstname`, u.`Surname`, u.`Email`) AGAINST ('foo')
OR MATCH(o.`Name`, o.`ShortName`) AGAINST ('foo')
```

The above query is slow, and so is the one searching only in the user's information:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation o
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation_member m ON m.`OrganisationId` = o.`OrganisationId`
LEFT JOIN dp_user u ON u.`UserId` = m.`UserId`
WHERE MATCH(u.`Alias`, u.`Firstname`, u.`Surname`, u.`Email`) AGAINST ('foo')
```

The query searching only in the organisation's information, however, is fast (around 25 times faster):

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation o
LEFT JOIN dp_organisation_member m ON m.`OrganisationId` = o.`OrganisationId`
LEFT JOIN dp_user u ON u.`UserId` = m.`UserId`
WHERE MATCH(o.`Name`, o.`ShortName`) AGAINST ('foo')
```

So it seems that I only get good performance when doing the fulltext search in the main table, and not the ones that are joined into that table. What can I do to get good performance when doing a fulltext search in a joined table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining FTS and JOIN in your queries results in a slow down because mysql generally uses only one index per table. When you perform a FTS on a table mysql uses the full text index on that table, thus it's not possible to use an index for the join.

In other news, the indexes on the dp_organisation_member table doesn't make a lot of sense. You have made the `user_id` field unique. That means a user can belong to only one organization, which actually means the dp_organisation_member table is redundant. You have over normalized. You can drop this table and add an organization id to dp_user and eliminate one of your joins.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to InnoDB for starters.  As of 5.6.4, `FULLTEXT` was available with it.  There are a [*few differences*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) to be aware of.

When the Optimizer has a choice between a `MATCH` and some other type of filter, it will do the `FULLTEXT`, not the other.

`WHERE MATCH... OR MATCH...`is bad because of the `OR`.  And `FULTEXT` does poorly here.  Turning it into `( SELECT ... MATCH ) UNION ( SELECT ... MATCH )` is a possible workaround.

`LEFT JOIN` likes to filter on the 'left' table first.  So it is ok for that table to use `FULLTEXT` but not the 'right' table.  In general, do not use `LEFT` unless you need it.